# Vuejs and VueRouter SEO

Tags: javascript, node.js, seo, vue.js

I'm using html5 push states and VueRouter. When I go onto google webmaster tools and crawl the site with a render, only what is outside of the `<router-view>` tag is rendered... I've tried using Prerender.io and it seems like it doesn't work with VueJS because I receive a 504 error on any page.

Any solutions or fixes to get google to render the entire page?

Answer (score -1):

504 means that there was a gateway timeout, which is network related, not Vue related. Vue should render just fine on google since the google spider supports javascript.

You can read more about the 504 status code here: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.5

Comment: Ok got it for the 504, thanks. Any input on solutions besides Prerender.io to fix the router-view issue? Seems like google is able to load and crawl javascript, I don't see why it won't load the router-view content

Comment: without code it would be hard to tell, but i think a error in the code might be the issue